# Why is hibernate session not closed after transaction is completed

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, transactional

I use Spring + hibernate for database access (mysql). For read only methods, I need to change the underlying connection status to read only so I can send read operations to slaves (in master-slave).

In the following code, I use hibernate session to change the underlying connection to read only in `getEmployer` method. This part works properly. 
I assume after the `getEmployer` method is executed, the session will be closed (since it is annotated by `@Transactional`). So when the `saveEmployer` method below is called, a new session will be started. Therefore the `connection.isReadOnly()` in `saveEmployer` should return `false`. But when I call `saveEmployer` method (after calling `getEmployer` method), the `connection.isReadOnly` turns out to be `true`.

I believe that the session is not closed after `getEmployer` method is executed. My understanding is that when methods are annotated with `@Transactional`, the session will be closed after the transaction is committed. Did I do anything wrong here? Why the `connection.isReadOnly()` in the `saveEmployer` method is `true`? Thanks.

```
@Service
class public EmployerServiceImpl implements EmployerService{
    @Inject EmployerRepository employerRepository;
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void getEmployer(long id){
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(new Work(){
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException{
                connection.setReadOnly(true);
            }
        });
        ......
        this.employerRepository.get(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveEmployer(){
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(new Work(){
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException{
               log.warn("connection status = " + connection.isReadOnly());
            }
        });
        ......
        this.employerRepository.save(employer);
    }
}
```

Here is the java configuration of dataSource in root context

```
@Bean
public DataSource springJpaDataSource()
{
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return lookup.getDataSource("jdbc/SpringJpa");
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
{
    Map<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action",
            "none");
    properties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider",
            "filesystem");
    properties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "../searchIndexesApplyJob");

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    factory.setDataSource(this.springJpaDataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.peer.site.entities", "com.peer.site.message",
            "com.peer.site.converters");
    factory.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
    factory.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
    factory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager()
{
    return new JpaTransactionManager(
            this.entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject()
    );
}
```

Comment: Does the ascendant caller annotated too with `@Transactionnal` ?

Comment: No. The caller of the getEmployer and saveEmployer are not annotated with @Transactional

Comment: It could be explained if your connection pool reuse the connection and does not reset the read only flag. What connection pool are you using?

Comment: I use hibernate + tomcat + mysql. Not sure what connection pool is used. I added dataSource configuration in the post. Hope that is helpful. I also suppose that the connection retrieved from connection pool is random? It seems in my case it always retrieves the same connection (which is set to be readOnly)? I wrote an interceptor that resets the connection status after method execution. But I am concerned I may do sth. wrong somewhere which can cause unintended consequences (e.g., if session is not closed after the transaction is committed).

Comment: If you are messing around with the status you also need to take care to reset it yourself!. It is beter to use `@Transactional(read-only=true)`. Which will set the flag and reset it. It will only do this if the most outer tx is readonly not for txs that participate in an on-going transaction. IMHO also your setup is flawed as the stuff doing a get and save should be in a single service method (looks like you aren't having a service but a repo layer and modify stuff outside of it).

Comment: @Deinum: In my post I constructed some naïve examples to illustrate the unexpected behavior (they are not the actual methods in my application). When I added readOnly=true in Transactional in the getEmployer method, the connection.isReadOnly() still returned false. Any clues why?

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: @Nicholas hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.6. I copied the maven dependency in a project from book "professional java for web applications". I found that it excludes the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api from the dependency. Not sure why they exclude it.

Comment: @Nicolas According to tomcat document, if a connection borrowed from the connection pool is modified, the pool will not reset it. I believe your theory now.

Comment: That `@Transactional(readonly = true)` doesn't work is strange. Have you tried to debug spring and especially `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect#beginTransaction` method to analyse what happens on the spring/hibernate side?

Comment: @Nicolas I have some trouble with debugger. But I read through all the methods in HibernateJpaDialect. beginTransaction() method set flush mode to manual if it is readOnly. Another function getJdbcConnection take readOnly as a parameter but does NOT do anything with it. It is strange. I believe the connection is not set to readOnly.

Comment: `HibernateJpaDialect#beginTransaction` calls `DataSourceUtils#prepareConnectionForTransaction` which calls the `connection#setReadonly`.

Comment: @Nicholas I used an older version of org.springframework. Updated it. everything works fine now using readOnly. Have been struggling with this for a while and finally it works. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the reason. In tomcat document, it says

> The only state the pool itself inserts are defaultAutoCommit,
>   defaultReadOnly, defaultTransactionIsolation, defaultCatalog if these
>   are set. These 4 properties are only set upon connection creation.
>   Should these properties be modified during the usage of the
>   connection, the pool itself will not reset them.

What happens is that the connection is reused. But the connection pool does not reset its state. So if you modify the connection status, you have to reset it since the connection pool will not reset it.

As others suggested, I set readOnly = true in @Transactional annotation which is a much cleaner way of doing it. But note that the version of the org.springframework has to be  >= 4.1. Prior to 4.1, the readOnly will only change the flush mode but not set the connection to readOnly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's easier to work using `@Transactional(readonly = true)` [like explained here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactional-query-methods) instead of manually setting this value on the native session.

And if the session will be reused by Spring depends on (probably nested) transaction demarcation and / or in which thread(s) your call is executed. It can be reused by the same thread (stored in a ThreadLocal). [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html) you can find further information.

Comment: For some reason @Transactional(readonly = true) never works for me. There are conflicting posts on the internet about this. Not sure why

Comment: If you have code with Transactional(readOnly=true) working properly, can you share the maven-dependencies you use?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa should provide everything you need